# Why is it takes so long to go hybernating after overheating

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, hp-pavilion, overheating

My laptop used to hybernate almost instantly after overheating.
But now it takes maybe few minutes now. The PC shows a black screen and runs few minutes then goes down. And it doesnt cools while showing the black screen.
It should take less than 5 seconds.

Edit: Overheating is obvious but why it doesnt hybernate quickly as it used to. From the overheating to go completely down process takes very long.

[image: sample screenshot from hp community]

Specs: win 10 up to date, toshiba SSD, HP laptop

Comment: So.. you want to fix it so it crashes harder/faster? Why not ask about how to stop it crashing in the first place?

Comment: its not crashing i think. it hybernating due to overheat. if i mismentioned. it happens only when gaming. ill edit and ill give a sample image from google for clarification of this error.

Comment: That is a crash by definition and no, it isn't hibernating. It clearly shows thermal **shutdown**.

Comment: @ChanganAuto any laptop can encounter thermal shutdown right? is this a fatal problem? But my PC used to shutdown quickly then i can continue to use few seconds later. But now it takes minutes even sometimes it takes 20 or so minutes to shutdown after black screen appears. My problem is that time is too long.

Comment: These thermal shutdowns are most definitely shortening the lifespan of your laptop's components. Your laptop is wrecking. You should fix the overheating problem, and you'll no longer have this issue as a result.

Comment: @hfc - Are you saying about your system goes into hibernation after it thermally overheats it takes 20 minutes to boot?  That sounds more like the system takes that long to be within operational thermal limits.

Comment: @Ramhound I was trying to say it takes up to 20mins, from OS boots down (whatever its called :) ) to PC completely goes down. I hope i clarified enough

Comment: @hfc - So it takes 20 minutes for the system to hibernate? That sounds like the processor so thermally throttled it’s barely functioning

Comment: @pigeonburger overheating only occurs when i play a game that needs high system requinments, mostly in hot days. This happens since i bought this PC. So i thought its ok for a laptop. This is my first laptop ever, maybe i wasnt knowing that it isnt ok. Isnt this normal for other Laptops? But it takes so long to go down when overheated unlike i first bought it. If overheating is a fatal problem, im gonna buy extra cooler or dismount its integrated keyboard. Dismounting completely solves overheating. But its awkward. Not playing some games works too. I can solve overheating but it would useless.

Comment: @Ramhound yes. it could be. If so then time difference to brand new laptop because of lack of available CPU power?

Comment: So should i dismount its integrated keyboard for sake of cooling?

Comment: @hfc - If your processor was running at 800 Mhz or lower it would explain the reason, it takes so long to prepare your system to go into a hibernated state.  As others have explained, you should address the reason your system is overheating, and automatically going into that state.  A system should never be overheating provided its properly cooled.  The rare exception is say a laptop, in a bag, you forgot to shutdown.  It shutting down due to heat, that would be normal, but this happening as often as it does as you described is NOT normal.

Comment: @hfc - I have no idea what you mean by "dismount it's integrated keyboard", if you mean remove the outer shell of the keyboard, that wouldn't be a real solution.

Comment: @Ramhound then my PC is flawed in the first time. Because why it overheats rather than lowering the FPS so it can handle A game. Even when it brand new it couldnt handle some games. But fps never drops significantly when playing.
Now im gonna try proper solutions and see. Rather than removing the shell. :)

Comment: @hfc - Your processor is probably thermally throttling itself, and that would affect your FPS, but it can only do so much before it reaches it's thermal limits.

Comment: @Ramhound then main problem should be that, it don't throttle early enough. Ill look for that then.

Comment: @Ramhound i changed power settings to best battery life. And limited to %95 CPU power from advanced settings. So overheating problem permanently ended.
So best performance option was a foolish choice that i preferred for years.
thank you for your help.